# zend framework2 install skeleton application ZendSkeletonApplication using composer

Tags: php, zend-framework2

When I trying install `ZendSkeletonApplication` , it throws error . I enter command in windows command line

`>>composer create-project -sdev --repository-url="http://packages.zen
dframework.com" zendframework/skeleton-application E:\php_apps\mopinion-cp`

I am getting error

```
[InvalidArgumentException]
 Could not find package zendframework/skeleton-application with stability st
able.

create-project [-s|--stability="..."] [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--repos
itory-url="..."] [--dev] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress]
[--keep-vcs] package [directory] [version]
```

The application found in https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication.. and used same command on there .

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use a not stable release, just add stability requirement to dev-master:

```
php composer.phar create-project --repository-url="http://packages.zendframework.com" zendframework/skeleton-application:dev-master path/to/install
```

Composer and Git is needed

Comment: What do you mean by "Use a not stable release"? The point is to use a stable release, can't we find one? :(

Comment: A stable release seems not to be available. The command works for me without providing the repository-url